# How many times static methods will be executed in java

Tags: java, static-methods

This is related to the below thread :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402564/how-do-static-methods-work

Suppose I have a static method in a class (TestClass), which queries the DB and stored it in a static variable, and returns it.

```
public static  List<MyClass> getMyData()
    {   
     setMyDataList(getMyNewData.execute());//DB Call and assigns the result to the static variable. 
     return myDataList;// returns the static variable
    }
```

In this case, say class A calls `TestClass.getMyData()` which fetches the data and stores in the `myDataList`, and then class B calls `TestClass.getMyData()`, will the DB be hit again ?

Comment: Everytime you call a method, the method is actually called. If you store the result in a variable and access only the variable, then it will be the variable which is read each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Static block is not equals to static method.**

```
In case of static block:
```

That static block loads when class loader loads that class. Unless you have multiple class loaders, only once it executes and that data you inserted will be shared across all the instances.

```
Incase of static method :
```

It's almost like an instance method and you'll be hit those many times you call that method. Diff is only you don't need an instance to invoke it.

You not at all need that method. Put your code in a static block an hit DB there and insert into list. You can access that list with static and don't forget to make that list  `static`.

Comment: But this is a method not a static block I guess.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This was my understanding too. But just got confused from some other sources. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

yes it will be 'hit' again...

If you don't want that you might want to have a flag in your static class that indicates if the method was already called:

```
private static boolean methodAlreadyCalled = false;

public static List<MyClass> getMyData()
{
    if (!methodAlreadyCalled)
    {
        setMyDataList(getMyNewData.execute());
        methodAlreadyCalled = true;
    }
    return myDataList;
}
```

Comment: If it is accessed by multiple threads then synchronization might be required. But OP has not mentioned about multi threading, so good.